# In post Rails 5.1, how does attribute_changed? chage for "validate" callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, callback, ruby-on-rails-6

In Rails 4.1, I used to invoke a validation method when an attribute is changed in my model

```
  validate :my_attribute_is_valid, if: :my_attribute_changed?
```

With Rails 5.1 and above (I’m using 6), the attribute_changed? Has changed for before_ and after_ callbacks (to saved_change_to_attribute? And will_save_change_to_attribute?, respectively).  What is the proper way to change the method check for “validate”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct would be: `will_save_change_to_attribute?`

Validations run before `save` callbacks, therefore, you won't be able to checked for `saved_changes` just yet. [Available callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

And as stated in the docs for [will_save_change_to_attribute?](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-will_save_change_to_attribute-3F):

> Will this attribute change the next time we save?
> This method is useful in validations and before callbacks to determine if the next call to save will change a particular attribute. It can be invoked as will_save_change_to_name? instead of will_save_change_to_attribute?("name").